# sent BCH to a BTC Segwit address

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash, segregated-witness, ledger-hardware-wallet

Is there a way to recover the BCH ?

Use his Ledger purse
I've sent BCH
To address BTC Segwit
This link is treated
https://explorer.bitcoin.com/bch/address/36CU6nDniJca1UVhvNhjsDdZpUsyYw5vSx

I want to get it back BCH

Comment: You need to get in touch with a miner. [BTC.com](https://bch.btc.com/docs/help/bch_segwit_recovery) offers a recovery service.

Answer (score 1):

Not without help of a BCH miner.  Basically there is no way to claim these coins under Bitcoin Cash since they unpicked all the SegWit changes prior to forking.

These coins are actually seen as "anyone can spend" coins on the BCH network (unlike in Bitcoin, someone claiming these is breaking no rules so the transaction would be accepted as valid), so a miner can claim these for themselves, if you find a good one, then you could politely ask them to claim them and forward them onto you.